make4ht with css styles. Remove margins
I have this Questions\285.tex file:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Something in this document. This paragraph contains no information and its purposes is to provide an \textbf{example} on how to insert white spaces and \textit{lines breaks}.\\
When a line break is inserted, the text is not indented, there are a couple of extra commands do line breaks. \newline
This paragraph provides no information whatsoever. We are exploring 
line breaks. \hfill \break
And combining two commands
\end{document}

And I have this make4ht.cfg file
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Css{
  margin-right: -7em; margin-left: 10px;
}
\EndPreamble

When I execute: make4ht Questions\285.tex -d output -B aux_output -c make4ht.cfg, the html output is:

The text seems to be centered. I want the text to be aligned to the left. How can I do that?

TeX4ht creates web pages that have set a maximal width because text with too long lines is hard to read. To prevent this behavior, you can use the nostyle option. You can set it even in the config file in the \Preamble command:
\Preamble{xhtml,nostyle}
\begin{document}
\Css{
body{
  margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; max-width: 80ch;

  }
}
\EndPreamble

You had an error in your CSS command; you always need to select an element to which the rule should be applied. For example, use body if you want to apply it to all text. In my version of \Css, I've set it to have small left and right margins, but also maximal width. You can set the value to a different value or remove it entirely if you don't want to have shorter lines.
This is the result:


Nice solution!!. Thanks!
